# How to get actual CPU time for some Python3 code

Tags: python-3.x, cpu-time

In general, I use `time.time()` to get CPU time for some my codes, for example:

```
import time
t_start = time.time()
my_code()
t_end = time.time()
cpu_usage_time = t_end - t_start
```

But actually, I don't know whether the `cpu_usage_time` is all used for my code or not, I think the actual time is less than or equal with `cpu_usage_time`.
I want to know how to get actual CPU time for my code with Python3.x built-in modules or functions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  `time.process_time()` method to get the value of the sum of system and user CPU time of current process.

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_time and https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time

hope to help you!